# Meta Query | Compare category name and meta value

Tags: categories, meta-value

I like to create meta query that has a condition like this.

Using comparison of meta value, and omitting articles which belongs to category that is same name of meta value.  Each article belongs to several categories.

This is what I made for it, but something wrong.  It fails to store category name of all articles.

```
<?php
$cats = get_the_category();
foreach($cats as $cat){
$category_name = $cat->cat_name;
}
?>

<?php
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type'   => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'meta_query' => array(
                'key'=> '1bb1',
                'value' => $category_name,
                'compare'=>'NOT LIKE',
                ),                   
);?>
```

Comment: categories are not post meta, they're stored as terms in a taxonomy and use different tables and APIs, you can't use `meta_query` to query a taxonomy

Comment: Hi  Im not compare taxonomy in meta query.  I try to store category name as argument first, then compare it in meta query.  My idea does not work?

Comment: `meta_query` is **only** for data stored as post meta, categories are not post meta

Comment: May I ask why are you storing, or trying to store, the category name in the post meta? Why not just use the `tax_query` parameter to exlude posts with certain tags from the query?

Comment: In your foreach loop you have a variable $category_name, which is a string. In your example this variable will keep only the last category name from the result of get_the_category() function. Also, this function returns an array of term objects, term object doesn't have a 'cat_name' property, just use 'name' instead, like this $cat->name

Comment: Hi Tom and Antti  I like to query following value of meta key 1bb1.  Not depending on category.  For example, Category is A and 1bb1 value is A, then its not shown.  Category name is A, and 1bb1 value is B, then its shown.

Comment: Hi Anton  Thank you for your advise.  Now I understand why it keeps only the last category name.